# json cannot be decode

Tags: json, curl

I have a problem with json,
I'm using PHP Curl to post file with form-data, and after post the Curl return some weird json

like this

```
{"code":200,"status":"Success","badges":{"id":"0d28f02d13fe4c7ca8681e2ed0224180","name":"test 5","description":"test 5","image":"http://somesite.id/images/d25273bdc1b54525a602dfca8ab826fdtest.jpg","category":"Upload","target":2}}
```

the problem is, the return result can't be json_decode, I know if this json weird, I can print but cannot be json_decode,

I not have acces to change API, I need the id from badges, 
is there any trick? or a way to get the id, or some modified so the return result can be decode

i have tried

```
$a = 'that result';
$b = "'".$a."'";

$c = json_decode($b);
```

but it still json format, not become array
need some idea and help, thx

EDITED:

let's say

```
$result =     {"code":200,"status":"Success","badges":{"id":"0d28f02d13fe4c7ca8681e2ed0224180","name":"test 5","description":"test 5","image":"http://somesite.id/images/d25273bdc1b54525a602dfca8ab826fdtest.jpg","category":"Upload","target":2}}

when I json_decode

$data = json_decode($result);
var_dump($result );
print_r($data);
```

it will return

```
{"code":200,"status":"Success","badges":{"id":"0d28f02d13fe4c7ca8681e2ed0224180","name":"test 5","description":"test 5","image":"http://somesite.id/images/d25273bdc1b54525a602dfca8ab826fdtest.jpg","category":"Upload","target":2}}bool(true) 1
```

Comment: you don't need to quote the json string, just straight up decode it. its valid anyway

Comment: The string you posted at the start is perfectly valid JSON, what makes you think it is not?

Comment: @ci_: Because (as it shows later in the question), he's *making* it invalid before trying to parse it.

Comment: When you decode the original - not modified - json string, you will likely get an object and not an array. Is that the problem perhaps? You should also post the exact output of `var_dump($your_json);` here.

Comment: yeah, i need get the ID, there is anyway to get the id? from the result

Comment: Your edit is not valid php. Voting to close as this does not seem to go anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$js='{"code":200,"status":"Success","badges":{"id":"0d28f02d13fe4c7ca8681e2ed0224180","name":"test 5","description":"test 5","image":"http://somesite.id/images/d25273bdc1b54525a602dfca8ab826fdtest.jpg","category":"Upload","target":2}}';
var_dump(json_decode($js,true));
```

Your Output will be

```
array (size=3)
  'code' => int 200
  'status' => string 'Success' (length=7)
  'badges' => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => string '0d28f02d13fe4c7ca8681e2ed0224180' (length=32)
      'name' => string 'test 5' (length=6)
      'description' => string 'test 5' (length=6)
      'image' => string 'http://somesite.id/images/d25273bdc1b54525a602dfca8ab826fdtest.jpg' (length=66)
      'category' => string 'Upload' (length=6)
      'target' => int 2
```

Comment: the problem is, the result is not string like $js you write
the result exactly like {"code":200,"status":"Success","badges":{"id":"0d28f02d13fe4c7ca8681e2ed0224180","name":"test 5","description":"test 5","image":"http://somesite.id/images/d25273bdc1b54525a602dfca8ab826fdtest.jpg","category":"Upload","target":2}} without quotes at start & end

Comment: the return not have any quotes marks, so it cant be directly decode using json_decode

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to put quotes around the string. Change

```
$a = 'that result';
$b = "'".$a."'";

$c = json_decode($b);
```

to simply

```
$a = 'that result';
$c = json_decode($a);
```

The JSON is valid. Putting the quotes around it *made* it invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The original response is correct JSON syntax. Don't add the extra quotes in 
 `$b = "'".$a."'"; //INCORRECT`

Instead try this, as an example:

```
/* $response is the result from API */
$response = '{"code":200,"status":"Success","badges":{"id":"0d28f02d13fe4c7ca8681e2ed0224180"}}';
$decoded = json_decode($response);
print_r($decoded); //See full decoded
$badge_id = $decoded->badges->id;
echo "The badge id is $badge_id \n";
```

Which would print:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [code] => 200
    [status] => Success
    [badges] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 0d28f02d13fe4c7ca8681e2ed0224180
        )

)
The badge id is 0d28f02d13fe4c7ca8681e2ed0224180
```

Comment: so how to get the json decoded? when decoded it return same json

Comment: @Mike: No, it doesn't. The JSON is a string. The result of decoding it is an object with various subobjects in it.

Comment: so it can't be decoding? I tried with Rob answer and it give me error 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ....(php file)